# Regex to allow only numbers and $ symbol

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a requirement where the user can enter only numbers and `$` symbol in a textbox. Anything else should not be allowed and it should show an alert message.

Comment: Google `html form validation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below function

```
function AllowNumbers(e, field) {
var val = field.value;
var re1 = /(^[0-9$]+)/g;

val = re1.exec(val);
if (val) {
    field.value = val[0];
} else {
    field.value = "";
}
}
```

and call this function on keyup of a textbox

Comment: So the minute the user inputs one invalid character you're going to wipe out everything he's entered so far? And why do you have two `^`?

Comment: Think your regex has a typo; the second `^` should be in the character class.

Answer (score 3):

```
^[\d\$]+$
```

To use this regex in the HTML input validation use regex

```
[\d\$]+
```

Explanation:

```
^ assert position at start of the string
[\d\$]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\d match a digit [0-9]
\$ matches the character $ literally
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Example:

```
$(function(){
    $('#text').keyup(function(){
        val = $(this).val();
        res = val.match(/^[\d\$]+$/);
        if(res == null){
            alert("Enter only $ or numeric");
        }
    })
})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/7aa1ophk/)

Comment: If the intent of the OP is to use the HTML5 validation feature, with the `pattern` attribute, then the `^` and `$` are implicit and not required.